# Microsoft Edge v41.x Truncating AngularJs 1.x expression markup

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, microsoft-edge

I am having issue using simple angular markup with the Microsoft Edge browser.

As soon as the angular expression markup becomes long Edge seems to cut it off at random.

For example:

```
ng-disabled="conditionOne || conditionTwo || conditionTwo || conditonThree"
```

Is reduced to:

```
ng-disabled="conditionOne || conditionTwo || conditio"
```

Has anyone else seen something similar to this behavior on Microsoft Edge? I am using Edge version v41 and Angular 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've faced this bug: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19090305/ ("checked attribute content is truncated to 128 characters").

Shouldn't happen with `ng-disabled`, only with `disabled`. Using `ng-disabled` can actually be a solution in this situation. Other attributes that are known to be broken are `required` and `checked`. Very likely, all so called boolean attributes are affected.

The best solution in this situation is to use the `x-` or `data-` prefix for the attributes broken in Edge (e.g. `x-required` instead of `required`). AngularJS normalizes attributes ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)) and strips these prefixes away.